# Lightning component not calling apex class for non system admin profile - setcallback state=error

Tags: apex, lightning

LC is working fine for System admin profile but for one other profile its not calling the apex class and the callback response is printing as:

```
state: ERROR
SendDocusignContract_LC.js:99 response: SecureAction: [object Object]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }
```

I checked the profile has access to all the fields used in LC and in inspect logs I am able to print it before state=error. The apex method is not getting called.

Edit - I am just calling a backend apex class and there is nothing as such in the component. The class returns a docusign url which then displays the DS UI for salesforce. So I think the LC is loading but not getting proper response.

When I run the code, I am not able to see any debug logs for my apex class

What else should I debug here, please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Is the class added to running user's profile?

Comment: Hi @Raul, no it was not. I didnt know about this. just added the class and its working fine now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from CRUD and FLS access, apex classes needs to be added to the profile.